# How do I sort custom taxonomy pages by custom date field in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, date, sorting, taxonomy

What I'd like to do is sort all posts that appear on pages filtered by different children of taxonomies, by a 'date' meta key.

I found this generic query_posts function:

```
query_posts('&meta_key=date&orderby=meta_value&order=DESC')
```

This grabs all the posts and places them on a single page, sorting these by my custom meta Key.  I would like to still keep the pages separated by their given taxonomy/terms, but sort all of these by this date meta_key. I hope I've explained this correctly. Thank you very much, anyone who can help!

Comment: Does anyone have views on this? I tried adding         `query_posts(array('post_type' => 'project','paged' => 0,'meta_key' => 'custom_date','orderby' => 'meta_value','order' => 'DESC'));`, which does exactly what OP says: grab ALL posts within taxonomy, regardless of terms. Desired effect would be to only show posts within the current taxonomy term, but sorted by the meta key `custom_date`. Seems fairly standard stuff, but cannot find a clear solution.